# Do I need to worry about software compatibility at all if I use Mono and Wine?

Tags: wine, mono

Do I need to worry what version of OS software runs on and what the software requirements are?  Can I can install any Windows software on Mono or Wine without worrying about compatibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those emulators are not perfect.  Try the application you want to use, but it may take some tweaking to get it working correctly.  See [WineHQ's support page](https://www.winehq.org/help) and [Mono's Documentation](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/) for help to get them working.

Answer (score 0):

In wine configuration I found I can run software as any windows version. So I can switch those version provided there as my software requirement.[image: Wine COnfiguration]